# Approach used in solving Popular Algorithmic Path Traversal Type

Tags: algorithm, matrix, dynamic-programming

- Given a matrix we have to select one value from each row so that the total value cost selected is minimum.
- Now the problem is we cannot select column "0" to  "J" in "I"th row if we have selected column "J" in the previous rows.
- That is, we are traversing only towards right we cannot come left as we move downwards.

*What I could think is if we start from the last row and then move upwards then we have to look for all the possible combination which is of time complexity `O(2^n)` but is there another efficient approach to solve this type of question?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a variant of [shortest path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem), where your graph is:

```
G = (V,E)
V = { (x,y) | for each cell in the matrix } U { (-1,-1) } //assuming 0 based matrix
E = { ((x1,y),(x2,y+1)) | x1 < x2 } // or x1<=x2 - depends if you can go straight down
w((x1,y1),(x2,y2)) = value(x2,y2) //weight function
```

Now, this is a graph (which is actually even [Directed Acyclic Graph - DAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph)) and you can apply a shortest path algorithm on it from a single source `(-1,-1)` to multiple targets of the format `(x,n-1)` - where `n` is the total number of rows. One algorithm to solve it is [Dijkstra's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm).

---

After understanding this is a DAG, we can even further optimize it with straight DP solution (that actually mimics the shortest path algorithm, but exploits DAG features):

```
D(-1,-1) = 0
D(x,y) = min { D(x', y-1) | for each x'>x }  U {infinity} + value(x,y)
```

And the final answer will be `min{ D(x,n-1) | for  all values of x}`.

This solution runs in `O(n*m*m)`, where `n` is the number of rows, and `m` is the number of columns.

Comment: So, between two rows there will be n*n edges??

Comment: @Arqam O(m*m) - assuming `m` is the number of columns. Also, see edit, we can exploit the fact that the graph is a DAG.

Comment: so there will be total of n*m*m edges with m*(n^m-1) paths. So, what you are suggesting is that I take all the columns in the first row as source one by one to see which one is minimum? Also there cannot be an edge between (x1,y1) (x2,y2) where y2<y1. y2 should always be bigger or equal to y1.

Comment: @Arqam I might have flipped the index, in here the idea is to move one by one on the `y` axis (down one row), and for each (x1,y1),(x2,y2) - there is an edge only if x1<x2 - it is explicitly written in the definition of `E`. Number of edges in total is `O(n*m*m)`, and this is also the run time of the algorithm.

Comment: So if I am using Dijkstra's then I have to take all elements in the first row as source one by one, and calculate the minimum cost by them ?

Comment: @Arqam No, that's why I introduced the dummy cell (-1,-1) - it is the only source

Comment: So, now I am putting everything in simple words. I have my source as (-1,-1). Now I will apply Dijkstras for the graph. I have a graph where there is an edge from x row and j column to x+1 row and for all column such that col > j.

Comment: Yes, and the shortest path with the weight function I described is the lowest path on your matrix.

Comment: if we use Dijkstras, we will be using Greedy technique in which we might not get the correct answer. For example if we have the source (-1,-1), then move towards the first row, it will always select the lowest cost edge, and if it is the 2nd last column then we will not be able to move down more than 2 rows. As J value should be more than the previous values.

Comment: @Hack109 No, if we use Dijkstra's algorithm, we will consider all possibilities, it is greedy to chose the path that leads to every vertex - but not greedy to chose the shortest path. If you understand the reduction to graph problem - from correctness of dijkstra -it works.